# Need only specific part of SQL data results. Any ideas?

Tags: sql, sql-server, trim

I have run into an issue and have searched far and wide without much success. I have a SQL statement that pulls account numbers. The account numbers consist of four parts, but I need to separate one of the middle parts into its own column. I've seen various TRIM methods, but nothing seems to be working.

Essentially the account number comes out as:

```
1    02   345678901
```

Basically the data has 19 characters. There is a number (the first `1`), four spaces, then two numbers (in this example the `02`), several more spaces, and then the rest of the account number. What I am trying to pull out is just the `02` in the middle there. But, the kicker is that that number may not always be a `02`. It can be 01, 02, 03... all the way to 29 I think is what we have.

I've tried using `LEFT(ColumnName, 7)` but that gives me the whole beginning. I've tried other variations but I feel like I am missing something obvious. Whatever the case, I just need the two numbers in the middle in their own column.

Any help or suggestions would be epically appreciated. Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they always have this format, then use `substring()`:

```
select substring(columnname, 6, 2)
```

Comment: Yup, substring worked. Wow how did I not see that? Ugh. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to mix LEFT() and RIGHT() functions to obtains what you need ?

Even simpler, use the substring() function.

Please check this page: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html

Comment: I tried the LEFT and RIGHT functions both, but it appears the substring() function is what I needed. Being relatively new to SQL and learning it on the job as I go, I still have a lot to learn. @_@;; Thanks so much for your help!